# Python - count the occurrences of a list of items in a list?

Tags: python, list, counter

Trying to count how many times a value from a list appears in another list.
In the case of:

```
my_list = [4,4,4,4,4,4,5,8]
count_items = [4,5,8]
```

this works fine:

```
from collections import Counter
print (Counter(my_list))
>> Counter({4: 6, 5: 1, 8: 1})
```

However, if my_list does not have any entries for '4', for example

```
my_list = [5,8] 
count_items = [4,5,8]
print (Counter(my_list))
>> Counter({5: 1, 8: 1})
```

While I am looking for this output:

```
>> Counter({4: 0, 5: 1, , 8: 1})
```

Comment: It's worth noting that attempting to access a key which does not exist in a Counter will return 0 for that item. So in this case `Counter(my_list)[4]` would return `0` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Counter` has no way to know that you would expect 4s to be counted, so by default only accounts for elements it finds in the list. An alternative approach would be:

```py
my_list = [5,8]
count_items = [4,5,8]
counter = {i: sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x == i else 0, my_list)) for i in count_items}
print (counter)
>> {4: 0, 5: 1, 8: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you need the value for?

Because the counter you have here actually returns 0 when asked for the key 4:

```
my_list = [5,8] 
count_items = [4,5,8]
counter = Counter(my_list)
print(counter)
>> Counter({5: 1, 8: 1})
print(counter[4])
>> 0
```

Comment: You can use this fact to generate the desired output as such: `{k: Counter(my_list)[k] for k in set(count_items)}`

Answer (score 0):

A counter *is a* dict and implements the update method, which preserves zeros:

```
>>> counter = Counter(my_list)
>>> counter
Counter({5: 1, 8: 1})
>>> counter.update(dict.fromkeys(count_items, 0))
>>> counter
Counter({5: 1, 8: 1, 4: 0})
```